# Does wrapping a line affect the private/public key in PHP?

Tags: php, rsa, private-key, public-key

I received a public key in the following format:

```
$publicKey = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAAASDF4QKBgQCMuZSztSi6iBLLxHquRomOXLW4WVtoovj8QqbUR8Bp1EiPsvN9Z9o4gCStacMAGWdvxH+V2vCZ7C66S+h2GTG45VBMfUeIfpc+Ta2593R10J34Vv+uKhPmTYNXASDH4howZMc0SK18ol7be63VtlwXGakNkLXsucGlTnfkWwGoQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';


$publicKey = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAAASDF4QKBgQCMuZSztSi6iBLLx
HquRomOXLW4WVtoovj8QqbUR8Bp1EiPsvN9Z9o4gCStacMAGWd
vxH+V2vCZ7C66S+h2GTG45VBMfUeIfpc+Ta2593R10J34Vv+uK
hPmTYNXASDH4howZMc0SK18ol7be63VtlwXGakNkLXsucGlTnf
kWwGoQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';
```

The difference is that the first one is not wrapped, otherwise, both strings are the same.

Both of them can do the encryption, but I am not sure if they are the same ones because of the line breaks.
I don't have the private key.

Does wrapping the key affect the value of the key?

Comment: This might help? https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19043/can-i-remove-newlines-in-a-public-key

Comment: No, line wrapping doesn't matter. It's a base64 encoding, and only printing characters are significant.

Answer (score 0):

Does wrapping the key affect the value of the key? : Yes it affects the key!

In the above case, both look the same, but both are different.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).